# How to store and analyze timestamped logs in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I have a lot of log lines, each with a time, that I want to store in HDFS and analyze. I want to run MapReduce jobs that will process only lines within a given time frame (last 5 minutes, last hour).

I'm looking for pointers to get started. And, any alternatives (e.g., storing the lines in hbase? Other platform?)

Comment: explain more detailed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My 2 cents :

You could use Hbase for that. Read in each line of your file, take out the TS field and use it as the rowkey and store rest of the line in a column. So our table would have just one column. This would allow you to do faster range queries, like you need(last 5 mins, last hour etc). And to avoid regionserver hotspotting, you could create pre-splitted tables.

Alternatively, you could store data in a Hive table partitioned by TS and then do the processing through HiveQL. Or bucket the data based on TS. Easy and straightforward.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

While the log processing can be done with Map/Reduce programs with combination of Hive/HBase, Hadoop approach may not fit well for processing the logs at frequent intervals as the Map/Reduce programs are built for batch processing. Combination of [Apache Kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/) and [Storm](http://storm-project.net/) fits well to process logs for your requirement

You may also look at this [link](http://www.drdobbs.com/open-source/easy-real-time-big-data-analysis-using-s/240143874)